# How to use has one through in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to ask, there are three tables I've created, the following tables is bellow

brands

- brand_id
- brand_name

motorcycles

- motorcycle_id
- brand_id
- motorcycle_name

purchases

- purchase_id
- motorcycle_id
- purchase_price
- purchase_location

How to get data purchase_id, motorcycle_name and brand_name ?
I tried to use hasOneThrough() with model like this :

```
class Purchase extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'purchase_id';

    public function motorcycleBrand(){
        return $this->hasOneThrough(Brand::class,Motorcycle::class,'brand_id','brand_id');
    }
}
```

And this is code inside controller :

```
$data = Purchase::->with(['motorcycleBrand', 'motorcycle'])->get();
return response()->json($data);
```

But it's not working, motorcycle data is showing but brand data is not showing (null).
Is it possible if I want to get data as I want ? If possible how to get it ?
Thank you..

Comment: You can't use hasonethrough inverse. If you want to get brand to purchase you can use `hasOneThrough` but for purchase to brand you need to use `belongsTo`

Comment: Likely just a typo when posting your question, but `Purchase::->with()` is a syntax error; for the first method, use `::`, then `->` for any chained methods.